# How to allow for a HTTPS request to local ip

Tags: javascript, https, request, localhost, ip

I deployed a web application which require to send request and get response from a local ip(ie. 192.168.0.123), which is actually a payment terminal.

It seems that this violate the entire https purposes, however I have no control on the payment terminal and it's address due to 3rd parties API.

Are there any workaround to handle localhost/ local ip  ith https request?

Comment: Why does it violate the HTTPS purpose? 192.168.0.123 is not a local IP. You don't have to do anything to allow HTTPS to a local IP. You can send requests to `https://127.0.0.1`, `https://localhost` or `https://192.168.0.123`.

Comment: @jabaa It looks like an IP of the local network that connects to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Teemu Where do you read this? I read: There is an app, that sends requests to a fixed IP (not localhost) and gets responses from there. It seems like OP believes, that you can't use HTTPS in a local network or with localhost.

Comment: @jabaa — `192.168.0.123` is in a private IP range typically used for **local** area networks. You *do* have to do something to allow HTTPS on any IP … which is run a server that listens for and can understand HTTPS requests.

Comment: @Quentin Exactly. There is no difference between WAN, LAN or localhost. But this question somehow indicates that you can't use HTTPS in a LAN or with localhost. OP isn't asking how to add HTTPS.

Comment: @jabaa — I read it as "Can't use HTTPS on a third-party system that has been connected to the LAN"

Comment: @Quentin That's an interpretation. OP didn't write that the payment terminal doesn't support HTTPS. OP wrote that you can't use HTTPS in a LAN. Currently, I don't know whether the payment terminal supports HTTPS. It's even unclear whether the payment terminal requires HTTPS and whether the frontend is hosted with HTTPS

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity, I could do better: 
The web app is currently on HTTP, I'd like to take it to HTTPS in the future, however like mentioned above, the receiving-end is a payment terminal, where I can communicate through a private/local address.

Which, however I have no control on this payment terminal, therefore unable to install anything to make this 3rd-party system HTTPS.

I started this from scratch as my own project, always try to come to a solution myself, didn't want to bother anyone, until I really tried. Hope this doesn't sound silly, and really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you sure the payment terminal doesn't support HTTPS? Most systems either initially support it with self-generated self-signed certificates or can be configured to use your uploaded certificate. What payment terminal do you use? Is it a device or a software?

Answer (score 1):

If you can install additional software on the payment terminal, then you could install another HTTP server that acts as a reverse proxy and listens on HTTPS.

You then make your requests to `https://192.168.0.123` and your reverse proxy forwards them to its `http://localhost`.

[Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) is a popular server for this purpose.

---

If you can't install additional software then you should look at using an isolated network instead.

It doesn't really matter if communication over a local network isn't encrypted if you completely trust every device that is connected to it.

Comment: Thank you Q. I just read about a self-signed certificate, do you reckon issuing this on the private IP will do the magic?  I will also be researching for isolated network.